# How to select specific lines of multiple data files

Tags: text-processing

I have many files like these:

file1:

```
 408.60 0.0847 
 370.03 0.1571 
 307.49 0.1492 
 297.12 0.0708 
 274.36 0.1989 
 251.27 0.1640
```

file2:

```
 391.06 0.0589 
 368.55 0.2293 
 313.87 0.0369 
 299.94 0.1432 
 288.61 0.2125 
 252.57 0.1238
```

file3:

```
 395.74 0.2439 
 372.76 0.0658 
 323.80 0.0026 
 287.41 0.3337 
 268.44 0.0860 
 259.44 0.0680
```

I want to select specific lines of each input file based on a selection criteria.  The selection criteria is:

a) the first column must be a number more than 290.00

b) the second column must be the highest number

c) print the line

The output should be like this:

```
370.03 0.1571
368.55 0.2293
395.74 0.2439
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct solution

```
for file in file{1..3}; do
    sort -rk2 "$file" | awk '$1 > 290{print;exit}'
done
```

Or without awk

```
for file in file{1..3}; do
    while read field1 field2 ; do
        [ "field1" -gt 290 ] && { echo $field1 $field2; break; }
    done <(sort -rk2 "$file")
done
```

Or awk alone

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 || $1 > 290 && max < $2 {
        max = $2
        if (FNR == 1 && max) {
            print line
            if ($1 <= 290)
                max = -1     }
        line= $0                     }
    END {
        print line }
    ' file{1..3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in file1 file2 file ; do cat $f | awk '{printf("%s %s\n",$2,$1)}' | sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf("%s %s\n",$1,$2)}' ; done
```

Comment: Instead of just writing some code without explanation, why not show what you are specifically doing in your code block and how it solves the issue. Also note that ``cat`` and ``tail`` are unnecessary since you are already using ``awk``.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, if you have GNU awk, which works by using the second field as an array index and using `asorti` to sort on that index at the end of each file

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE{delete a}
  $1+0 > 290 {a[$2]=$0; next;}
  ENDFILE{n = asorti(a,b); print a[b[n]]}
' file{1..3}
 370.03 0.1571 
 368.55 0.2293 
 395.74 0.2439
```